# Access further pages in PDF only when the reader agrees to the terms and conditions

Tags: pdf, pdf-form

Like a self-executing NDA (Non-Disclosure Agreement), I need to have a PDF that shows the NDA terms and conditions on first page with buttons - `Agree` or `Disagree`.

Upon `clicking Disagree`, the `PDF should close and prevent access to further pages`. And upon `clicking Agree`, the `PDF should remain open and allow access to further pages`.

How can I do this? My constraint is that I must use PDF only.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which PDF viewers do you want to support? Please be aware that even a partial implementation of your requirements will at least require Javascript which is not available on all viewers.

Comment: @mkl, I am targeting the desktop-based PDF viewers and not the web browser based.

Comment: *"desktop-based PDF viewers"* - That's a very broad category also containing many viewers without Javascript support.